# Setting Up Parse Server on Windows

Tags: node.js, git, mongodb, parse-platform

I am trying to set up parse on my windows computer. I installed Python, and downloaded the parse-server and mongodb-runner  from github. When I try to follow the instructions in the read me of parse server I get the following errors in command prompt: [Command Prompt Run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZvrYg.png) [Git Shell run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2dmpC.png)
 The first picture is of the errors when I run the command `npm install -g parse-server mongodb` in command prompt. I thought the errors were occurring because of the git so I ran it in the git shell. The second picture is of when I run it in gitshell. I'm sorry I could not post the other part of the second run because of my reputation being too low. Does anyone have experience with parse or mongodb? and if so what might I need to change?

Comment: "npm install -g parse-server mongodb" in Windows seems ok. "npm install" in parse-server folder is ok, too. The error shows in 2nd, babel is not found. 'babel, babel.cmd' should in "xxx\node_modules\.bin" .

Comment: I do not see babel.cmd in the bin file I see another file named "node-gyp-bin", npm, npm.cmd,npm-cli.js, and read-package-json.js. Should I reinstall nodejs?

Comment: You just do not install babel or get it correctly. Do you clone the parse-server from github? babel is one of the dependencies or dev-dependencies, see this. https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/blob/master/package.json

Comment: Yes I cloned pase-server from github. I installed babel using these [directions](https://babeljs.io/) and in the gitshell I got the error `babel src/ -d lib/` which I think is the same problem I will reclone the repository and try again.

Comment: Have you found a solution?